# Azure DevOps - deny access to repo

Tags: azure-devops

In Azure DevOps, is it possible to have users accessing all services except for the repo? By that I mean they should not be able to see any sourcecode.

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

You can set deny permissions for all Git repositories for a project, or for a single repository.

1. Open the web portal and choose the project where you want to add users or groups.
2. To set the set the permissions for all Git repositories for a project, choose Git Repositories and then choose the security group whose permissions you want to manage.
3. Set all the permissions to "Deny" and then save the changes.

[image]